# How do I copy one image to another using Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a sheet that I'm using to create sports cards.  There are 15 cards in my sheet, each with an image on it created by "INSERT -> Picture" and choosing a PNG or JPG from my computer.

However, since this sheet is a template used for many teams, I'd like the ability to create some code that lets me select one image, change it to a new logo, and copy that image to the remaining 14 on the click of a button.  I've tried a number of different things, all off of some variation like this:

```
Dim setLogo As Picture
Dim logo1 As Picture
Set setLogo = Sheets("Team Cards").Images("LOGO_SET")
Set logo1 = Sheets("Team Cards").Images("LOGO1")
logo1.Picture = setLogo.Picture ' also tried UserPicture
```

I've been googling around, but I can't seem to find the code that will do this.  I was messing around with PictureData property as well, but couldn't get that to work, they all ended in an error being thrown.  I saw some stuff about deleting the image and re-inserting a new one that I might try next, but I'm hoping I'm just missing some property that does this for me.  Can you assist with the right code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ChangeLogo macro

- Run the macro and a file dialogue appears.
- Browse and select the Logo Image for the Active Sheet's Cards.
- The new logo is added to the Shapes collection.
- Every shape in the Active Sheet is considered:
- If it is not the newly added logo shape and
- If the shape is an image, then for this found image:

  - The logo shape is duplicated.
  - The duplicate logo is updated with the found image's properties.
  - Then the found image is deleted.

ChangeLogo

```
Option Explicit
'
' ChangeLogo: File Dialogue Prompts user for Image.
'   The selected image replaces all the images on the Active Worksheet
'
Private Const GetDirStartIn = "" ' "CurDir" (Default), "ActiveWorkbook.Path", "/Specified/Path"
Private Const ImageFileExt = "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png" ' FileFilter Format
'
' More than one Shape can have the same name. Consider naming all images "Card Logo"
'    Rename: Home (tab) | Editing (section) | Find & Select | Selection Pane...
' TODO implement
' Leave Picture Blank "" to replace all on active sheet.
'Private Const BaseName = "Picture"
'Private Const FirstNumber = 1 ' Name is BaseName & " " Number
'Private Const LastNumber = 4

Public Sub ChangeLogo()
    Dim fname As String
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim logo As Shape
    Dim l As Shape
    Dim newLogoShapeName As String
    newLogoShapeName = "newLogoShapeName_Temp_DeleteMe"

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = " Card Logo - Select Image for Sheet"
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        If GetDirStartIn = "CurDir" Or GetDirStartIn = "" Then 'Default
            .InitialFileName = CurDir & Application.PathSeparator
        ElseIf GetDirStartIn = "ActiveWorkbook.Path" Then
            .InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator
        Else
            .InitialFileName = GetDirStartIn & Application.PathSeparator
        End If
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Images", ImageFileExt, 1
        .Filters.Add "All files", "*.*"
        .FilterIndex = 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            fname = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            End 'Exit Subroutine and Execution Call Stack
        End If
    End With
    Set logo = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(fname, msoFalse, msoTrue, 1, 1, -1, -1)
    logo.Name = newLogoShapeName

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        With shp
            If .Type = msoPicture Then
                ' More Logic based on template image shape names
                If .Name <> logo.Name Then
                    Set l = logo.Duplicate
                    l.Name = .Name
                    l.Top = .Top
                    l.Left = .Left
                    ' Deal here with letter boxing VS stretching to fit.
                    'l.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                    'l.ScaleHeight Factor:=1, RelativeToOriginalSize:=msoTrue
                    'l.ScaleWidth Factor:=1, RelativeToOriginalSize:=msoTrue
                    l.Height = .Height
                    l.Width = .Width

                    .Delete
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next shp
    logo.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: This is freakin' brilliant.  Thanks, Ted! I'm a programmer by trade, but VBA is a whole different world ;)

Comment: Pascal, Fortran, Cobol, Unix Shells, Ed, Sed, Awk, Javascript, VBS, VBA, C, C++, Java, SQL, PLSQL, Assembly (2). There are a few more I'm sure, just don't come to mind. No Pearl, Python etc, but I read them ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use copy-paste, like this:

```
Cells(1, "A").Copy
Cells(2, "A").select
activesheet.paste
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a chunk of code I use to copy images from one worksheet to another while sizing and positioning in them 2 up in the new sheet. wsData is the source worksheet and wsCharts is the target worksheet.

```
  iChartCount = wsData.ChartObjects.Count()
  If Not (iChartCount > 0) Then
    MsgBox "No charts in Data sheet to copy"
  End If
  For iChart = 1 To iChartCount
    Application.StatusBar = "CopyCharts: " & iChart & " of " & iChartCount & " " & Format(iChart / iChartCount, "0%")
    wsData.ChartObjects(iChart).Activate
    Set oChart = ActiveChart
    Set oChartObject = oChart.Parent

    lngChartHeight = oChartObject.Height
    lngChartWidth = oChartObject.Width

    oChart.ChartArea.Copy

    wsCharts.Select
    wsCharts.Paste
    wsCharts.ChartObjects(iChart).Activate
    Set oChartObject = ActiveChart.Parent
    lngChartTop = Int((iChart - 1) / 2) * lngChartHeight

    oChartObject.Top = lngChartTop
    ievenodd = iChart Mod 2
    If ievenodd = 1 Then
      oChartObject.Left = 0
    Else
      oChartObject.Left = lngChartWidth
    End If

  Next iChart
```